# uitextview keyboard hiding error

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

In my application am using `UITextView` in `UIScrollView`,I added the code to to hide ,it is not working.Here my code

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    [txt1 resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is okay. Just replace

```
[txt1 resignFirstResponder];
```

with

```
[textView resignFirstResponder];
```

And make sure your `textView` delegate is set to be `YES` other wise `delegate` method would not be call.

```
textView.delegate = self;
```

If you have been taken your `textView` from `XIB` then **ctrl+drag** from `textView` to `File'sO Owner` and set its `delegate`. It would work for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer:-

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
}
```

In `resignFirstResponder` will work with `UITextView` reference.You have given like

```
[text resignFirstResponder];
```

Which will not work.

Comment: if condition should be true.did you check that?

Comment: How can i orient my keyboard while typing in uitexview,it hides almost full uitextview .can you help me out

Answer (score 0):

You should return false. Like : - (Assume txt1 is your text view's obj)

```
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    [txt1 resignFirstResponder]; // OR [textView resignFirstResponder];
return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following code:

```
-(void)touchesBegan :(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    [self.view resignFirstResponder];

    [scrollView resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Then you can touch anywhere else other then textView to make the keyboard hide.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this ,

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldReturn:(UITextView *)textView
{
    // the user pressed the "Done" button, so dismiss the keyboard
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
  if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) //Resign for return Key
  {
    [textView resignFirstResponder];
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:-

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [txtView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use bellow code if you want to resign keyboard with enter key press fro every textview..

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    if([text isEqualToString:@"\n"])
    {
        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```